# SQL Saturdays, anyone familiar with them?

Tags: discussion

http://www.sqlsaturday.com/ <-- they're NOT JUST devoted to databases, but it happened to start off with that moniker once upon a time. They do have tracks on dba tasks tho, so that would be a good place for us to be affiliated with.

Anybody know this group and have some inside leads?

Comment: looks like they have sponsors, so if you get contact info and details, you can forward it on to the community team. We always like swag opportunities too..

Comment: @Jeff - "swag"? That means stolen goods where I come from :)

Comment: @JeffAtwood PASS is one of the primary folks on this. (http://www.sqlpass.org/) ~ One of the groups I'm trying to pester into talking to me (as a community member, so I'm _passionate_ ;) )

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the group is run by the Professional Association of SQL Server - http://sqlpass.org.  There are dozens of us associated with it.

Every SQLSaturday is run by local volunteers.  If you're looking to sponsor a particular city, go to its SQLSaturday page and go through the contact process.

Can you be more specific about what you're looking for?

Edit - also, just to be clear, SQLSaturday is indeed dedicated to databases, and to be more specific, Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: ~ See what Jeff said above about general sponsorship. I've got the contact info for my local city, but I did want to see if anybody here had affiliation with other venues and wanted to get in touch with those venues as well.

Comment: I also did not associate the fact that I've seen you on posts here meant that you were affiliated with the site. I was just talking with someone the other day about reaching out to you and a couple other people to see how you felt about this site and maybe doing a little evangelization for us over some of the other sites where people could look for help. I realize that that's a moneymaking venture for you right now, but perhaps there's some utility in general answers here none-the-less.